# Translation Golf XXXII - The power of words

Tags: traducción, translation-golf

> We have a winner! **Ender Look**, with [an 85-letter answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/24171/translation-golf-xxxii-the-power-of-words/24216#24216), found the true name of Victory.

---

Welcome to a new edition of the game!
If this is your first time, there's some info for beginners at the end of this post.

---

This edition's proposed text is a quote from Patrick Rothfuss's [*The Name of the Wind*](http://kingkiller.wikia.com/wiki/The_Name_of_the_Wind):

> Words are pale shadows of forgotten names. As names have power, words have power. Words can light fires in the minds of men. Words can wring tears from the hardest hearts. There are seven words that will make a person love you. There are ten words that will break a strong man's will. But a word is nothing but a painting of a fire. A name is the fire itself.
>
> <sub>(280 characters)</sub>

---

The goal is to translate the given text to Spanish, using as few letters as possible, while keeping all the original text's meaning and concepts more or less intact.

Here's a (non-golfed) example translation:

> Las palabras son pálidas sombras de nombres olvidados. Igual que los nombres tienen poder, las palabras tienen poder. Las palabras pueden encender fuegos en las mentes de los hombres. Las palabras pueden arrancar lágrimas de los más endurecidos corazones. Existen siete palabras que lograrán que una persona te quiera. Existen diez palabras que romperán la determinación de un hombre fuerte. Pero una palabra no es nada más que el dibujo de una hoguera. Un nombre es el fuego mismo.
>  
>  <sub>(395 characters)</sub>

---

- Rules: [Translation-golf rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/5481)
- Letter counter: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/)

You may want to check past [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf) questions to get a feel of the game dynamics and the kind of answers expected.

Want to share translation ideas, ask for clarifications or just tease other contesters? Join us in [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-tertulia), Spanish.SE's official chat room!

Have fun!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### <s>114 98 90</s> 85 Caracteres

> Voces: destellos del fuego de alias dejados. Igual, con poder: para inspirar, o hacer llorar. 7 unen, 10 rajan.

- *Voces: destellos del fuego de alias dejados*: En esta frase, el `:` lo uso para otorgarle definición a `voces` (lo mismo que decir "las voces **son** destellos...").

  - Nota: en esta frase he combinado tanto la primera como la última sentencia. No sabia que se podía hacer eso hasta que leí la respuesta de [@Charlie](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/24180/16980) (las reglas de translation golf no lo indican, aunque tampoco lo prohíben).
  - **Voces**: Es bastante poco común, pero `voces` puede usarse como palabras en textos formales (y antiguos, supongo).
  - **Alias**: Alias es sinónimo de nombre. (Para ser exactos, el alias también se puede interpretar como un apodo o sobrenombre.)
  - **Dejados**: Lo utilizo en reemplazo de olvidado (como se olvido ya no se usa, entonces se deja).
  - **Destellos**: Aquí combino mi antiguo significado de trazas y dibujos. Los destellos son como pantallasos, en otras palabras, un destello es como una imagen incompleta (cuando ves un destello/pantallaso de algo es que lo viste muy rápido, por lo que no pudiste prestarle mucha atención), por lo que no es realmente fuego, es solo una imagen, y a su vez es incompleta, ya que ni siquiera es una imagen en si, es algo que se ve rápidamente.
- *Igual, con poder*: "Igual [que los alias anteriormente mencionados] con[/tienen] poder". Aquí nuevamente vuelvo a utilizar el `,` para tratar de demostrar que los dos objetos son similares (me apoyo en el "igual"). Espero que se entienda la explicación, no se me ocurre como explicarlo mejor.
- *para inspirar, o hacer llorar*: Vuelvo a utilizar el `:` para darle definición a lo anterior (haciendo referencia al termino principal: `voces`), esta vez el `,` es usado más cerca de la enumeración (las voces realizan varias cosas, como inspirar, hacer llorar , etc).

  - **Inspirar**: Despertar o causar en el ánimo un sentimiento, una sensación o una impresión.
  - **Hacer llorar**: Lo mismo de provocar o arrancar lágrimas.
- *7 ligan, 10 rajan*: El `,` se usa como en la anterior vez, "7 [de estas (las voces)] ligan" o "7 [voces (recuerden que voces es sinónimo de palabras)] rajan" (lo mismo con 10). Use `ligan` y `rajan` basándome en [@Charlie](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/24180/16980), si puedes usar estas palabras para que alguien se enamore de ti (enamorar -> ligar), y el otro puede usarlas para que vos te enamores de él (enamorarte -> ligarte), básicamente estas palabras son capaces de enamorar a cualquiera (enamoran -> ligan a cualquiera). Lo mismo ocurre con rompen -> rajan.

  - **Rajan**: quebrantar o romper, al no especificarse nada más se puede entender que rompen o quiebran psicológicamente o físicamente a algo o alguien, pero sabiendo que solo se puede ligar (enamorar) personas (no objetos) y que enamorar es una acción psicológica (no física como romper algo), se puede deducir que se aplican los mismos principios a `rajar`.
  - **Ligar**: enamorar, conseguir pareja.

Espero que se entiendan mis explicaciones!

Comment: @blonfu, oh, perdón. No sabía que esta prohibido extraer fragmentos de diversas respuestas para formar una con la mejor parte de cada una (pero que aún sea coherente), cuando leí las reglas no estaba ese punto. Borrare mi respuesta ahora mismo, lo siento.

Answer (score 4):

## 183 caracteres

> Las palabras son sombras de nombres olvidados y como estos tienen poder. Arden en las mentes de los hombres. Entristecen al más duro corazón. Hay 7 que dan el amor; 10 que someterían a cualquiera. Son la foto de la luz de un nombre.

Answer (score 3):

#### <s>217 209 194</s> 136 caracteres

> Poderosas voces, eco de nombres olvidados que prenden mentes y
>   ablandan a los duros, 7 te darán amor, 10 quebrarán al fuerte; una es
>   solo la idea del fuego que un nombre es.

**voz.** 5. f. Palabra o vocablo.

Answer (score 3):

#### <s>206 204</s> 197

> Palabras, pistas, alias omitidos. Como alias tienen poder, igual palabras. Pueden asar fuegos en ideas del hombre. Sacar lloros de duros corazones. 7 de ellas harán a algún querer. 10 romperán un varón fuerte. 1, boceto de brasas. El nombre es fuego.

Answer (score 3):

#### <strike>142 108</strike> 92 caracteres

> Palabras: trazas, flébiles luceros, pinturas del fuego que eran (y son) los nombres. Hay 7 para chalar, 10 para romper.

Aclaraciones:

- [Traza](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aY0DN51): huella, vestigio.
- *[Chalar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8U9v4MV)* es sinónimo de *enamorar*.
- Se fusiona la primera frase con la última. Así, se indica que los nombres eran fuego, pero ya no lo son porque su poder se ha olvidado.
- Ya puestos, se fusiona la segunda frase con la primera, con lo de "flébiles luceros". Según la definición del DLE: *[flébil](http://dle.rae.es/?id=I4AiNkr)* es "digno de ser llorado" y también "lamentable, triste, lacrimoso". Y *[lucero](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NeJUIRh)* tiene una acepción que es "postigo de las ventanas por donde entra la luz". En dos palabras digo que iluminan y hacen llorar.

Comment: Oh! interesante reducción. Lo que no me convence mucho es que los nombres ya no sean fuego, aunque esten olvidados no dejan de ser lo que son.

Comment: @walen bueno, el original dice "they can light fires", que cuando se tradujo por "iluminan mentes" no hubo problemas, en el sentido que son capaces de arrojar luz, aunque sea en su sentido metafórico. Luego decir que las palabras son "luceros" no lo veo mal. Una de las acepciones de "lucero" es "ventana o postigo por donde entra luz", lo cual encaja muy bien dado que no se dice que sean fuego pero sí que dejan pasar la luz.

Comment: @walen más me preocupan otras traducciones que dan a entender que necesitas 7 palabras (cualesquiera) para enamorar y 10 para quebrar. Yo he intentado mantener que hay que saber cuáles son esas 7 o 10 palabras.

Comment: Bueno, todos nos dejamos cosas por el camino en esta vorágine reductora :). En tu caso no queda claro que una sola palabra no es más que un reflejo del verdadero fuego sino que parece que todas las palabras lo son.

Comment: @blonfu hum, yo había entendido lo de "a word is nothing but..." como hablando de las palabras en general, no de una en particular... Que igual lo he entendido mal, no sé...

Comment: Tambien puede ser, igual soy yo el que lo ha entendido mal.

Comment: @walen seguro que sí, pero yo ahora acabo de empezar a jugar al Zelda Breath of the Wild en la Switch, y tengo para rato... :-D